# latest version pentaho to solve an error with oracle in pentaho 8.1

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

Good morning,
After a few days trying to pass a parameter to a sql and give me error, after configuring in any way possible, I have come to see that there is an error that can not be done (https://jira.pentaho.com/ browse / PRD-6006? attachmentViewMode = list). They say that in the last release it is solved. I have 8.1.0.0.365. where is the last one downloaded? I do not find anything more current than mine.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, this happens from time-to-time. Mostly because of the Software Peter principle. Instead of checking on the net and in the forums that what you have under the eyes does not possibly exists, publish the error.By giving us a glimpse to this unobservable universe, we may help you in finding a paranormal solution.

Comment: The error is the same as the one that appears in this jira ticket:
https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-6006?attachmentViewMode=list
What happens is that you can not pass parameters to sql in oracle database. In jira it says it is fixed in version 8.1.0.2 but it is not published. I just saw that in github is the code of 8.1.0.2 but now I'm in trouble to compile it. Any help where to find this version or how to compile it?

Comment: According to the discussion, the patch is done on github so it's going to be available in 8.0.3 (a 9.0 usually comes in November). Do you have a EE license, so that you can put a request on the zen desk?

Comment: I have a community license, anyway I had an answer that was solved in 8.1.0.2

Comment: So you need somebody to compile the java class for you?

Comment: nothing, i solved the problem. i compiled with maven, changed some configuration and all is ok. thank you